# Understanding data balancing in sklearn cross-validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm currently trying to run sklearn's `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` cross validation on my very imbalanced data. I'm using a `LogisticRegression` model with the `class_weight='balanced'` parameter which, in my understanding, should balance my data. With this, I run the `cross_val_score()` method. I'm pasting a little snippet of my code here:

```
model = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', solver='liblinear',
                max_iter=1000, class_weight='balanced')
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=2, random_state=1)
accuracy = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
precision = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='precision', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
recall = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='recall', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
```

The results I'm getting show a very high average accuracy (94%) and very low average precision (5%) and recall (1%). This confuses me because the only way I can see this happening is if I have many more examples in one class than the other, which confused me because I thought my logistic regression model balanced the data.

I am wondering if my cross validation only applies this balancing to the training split it makes and not to the test split. This would explain how I could have such high accuracy and low precision/recall.

Alternatively if anyone knows a way to print out confusion matrices or even predictions for my cross validation using `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` that would be very helpful! It seems like those methods don't work with my choice of cross val, however I'd love to be able to debug by looking at the data and/or classification results.

Comment: I am afraid you are confused; `class_weight='balanced'` does not balance the data themselves, it only gives different weight to the classes (inversely proportional to their actual proportions in the data). And this weight scheme is only applied to the train set - in the test set it is just meaningless.

Comment: Oh i see. So what exactly does weighting do then? It doesn't select samples from the training set to have a more equal proportion of the two classes? And thanks for clarifying about the test set, that helps a _lot_!

Comment: Weighting weighs more the (fewer) minority class instances in the calculation of the training error. But this is not a *programming* discussion; i kindly suggest you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info and post a question in some relevant SE site.

Answer (score -1):

For evaluating model performance the target is likely highly skewed. Even with `class_weights='balanced'`, the classifier was unable to predict the minority class well. This is why the model made many low predictions (`predict_proba` closer towards 0), thus usually predicting the majority class and having a high accuracy score.

What you could try is instead of `class_weights='balanced'`, you can assign much more weight to the minority class. For example, `class_weights={0:1, 1:3}` would make the `0` class have a weight of 1 and the `1` class have a weight of 3.

Comment: This is exactly what `class_weight='balanced'` does, and by using the exact ratio of the class proportions instead of ad hoc numbers; OP says their data is "very imbalanced", so why do you assume that weighting the minority class 3x would be "much more" than the balanced one?